# ggplot2 histogram: show only bins with more than 2 observations

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to create a histogram for the distribution of a variable. For reasons of data censoring, I am only allowed to show bins with more than two observations. Is there a way to easily accomplish this task in ggplot2? 
Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(
  weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5), rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5)))
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count.. + 2, label=..count..), geom="text")
p
```

How can I restrict the histogram to only show the bins with n>2 observations? 
Maybe there is also a way to set the binwidth from the start so that no bins with less than 3 observations are created?
I hope my question is precise enough, and thanks for your help!

Comment: by the way, I have two complaints about ggplot2 histograms. First is the default number of bins - I typically use [the Freedman-Diaconis rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedman%E2%80%93Diaconis_rule) via `nclass.FD()` as it provides a pretty good default in most cases. The second is that the default boundaries are somewhere between questionable and downright misleading (see [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2323) for details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite easy with ggplot2. I don't think the plot itself makes any sense, but the idea could have utility outside this. You can use `ifelse` conditions inside `aes()` without any issues.

```r
library("ggplot2")
## set superior seed ;)
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5), rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5)))
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count.. + 2, label=..count..), geom="text")
p
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

```r
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=weight, y = ifelse(..count.. > 2, ..count.., 0))) +
  geom_histogram() +
  stat_bin(aes(label=..count..), geom="text")
p
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Not the most convenient, but you could calculate the bin heights externally (maybe this helps: https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/hist-data-without-plot-td796275.html), then filter the binned data and then plot the histogram providing both x and y aesthetics and stat="identity".

Alternatively to physically removing bins with few observations (ie. if you want to reuse the binned data for other stuff), you can use a third boolean variable that describes whether each row (ie. bin) meets your criterion and use it as a fill colour. Then set scale_fill_manual(values=c("transparent", "black")), which will make bins with FALSE in the criterion column transparent.

Answer (score 1):

It's do-able, and my advice is you have to decide the bins before hand, otherwise the filtering doesn't make sense.

We start with your example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(
  weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5), rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5)))
)
```

We need to define the bins, in this case, we have a bin every step of 1, e.g 40,41,42..

```
BREAKS = seq(floor(min(df$weight)),ceiling(max(df$weight)),1)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) +
  geom_histogram(breaks=BREAKS) +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count.. + 2, label=..count..), breaks=BREAKS,geom="text")
```

We can also manually calculate this using the hist function in base R and plot it as a bar:

```
h <- hist(df$weight,breaks=BREAKS,plot=FALSE)
dat <- data.frame(weight=h$mids,n=h$counts)

p2 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=weight,y=n)) + 
geom_col() + geom_text(aes(label=n),vjust=-0.5,size=3)
```

We put them together, and they are the same, except for a small difference in appearance
[image]

we define the cutoff and just plot a subset of the tabulated counts:

```
CUTOFF=2
ggplot(subset(dat,n>CUTOFF),aes(x=weight,y=n)) + 
geom_col() + geom_text(aes(label=n),vjust=-0.5,size=3)
```

[image]